# Apache ProxyPass and Sessions

Tags: apache, session, glassfish-3, mod-proxy

So I'm using Apache to proxy a specific folder to a Glassfish instance. The rules in my conf are:

```
ProxyPass /folder http://localhost:28083
ProxyPassReverse /folder http://localhost:28083
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /folder http://localhost:28083
```

It's working fine, except for the sessions. For every subfolder a new session is created.

So while I stay in one folder, the session persists, but as soon as I jump into another folder a new session is made.

How can I have one session for all subfolders?

Answer (score 5):

As covener already mentioned, the second parameter of `ProxyPassReverseCookiePath` should be a path. Be aware that the parameters are switched compared to the other directives, so in your case it would be:

```
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /folder
```

(Technically, this should not be necessary for it to work, as cookies from the path `/` are also available in `/folder/`, but it might cause them to interfere with the cookies of other web applications that you are running on the same domain.)

In addition, you might want to transform the cookie domain as well (unless you access your application only through `http://localhost/folder/`):

```
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain localhost example.com
```

`example.com` is the domain over which your web application is accessed.

Answer (score 1):

ProxyPassReverseCookiePath's 2nd parameter should just be a path, not a full URL.  Apache can't properly fixup the path baked into the cookie w/ the current invalid usage.

Comment: Be aware that the parameters of `ProxyPassReverseCookiePath` are switched compared to the other `ProxyPass` parameters.