# express.js sessions with reverse proxy

Tags: apache, node.js, session, proxy, express

I've setup an Apache reverse proxy to forward `api.mydomain.com` to `localhost:2000` which works just fine.

However, the real issue i'm having is in regard to sessions - it seems that the req.session's aren't being stored when querying via `api.mydomain.com`. Sessions will work just fine visiting from `localhost:2000`.

I assume this has something to do with the proxied domain...

server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.enable('trust proxy');

app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({ secret: 'supersecret'});
    app.use(app.router);
});

app.get('/session', function(req, res, next){ 
    console.log(req.session.username)
    // this will be undefined when called from  api.mydomain.com...
});


app.post('/session', function(req, res, next){ 
    req.session.username = 'my username';
});
```

apache config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName api.mydomain.com   
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:2000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:2000/

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain api.domain.com localhost:2000
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /
</VirtualHost>
```

**EDIT**

Notably, for further testing - adding the below code before `app.use(app.router)` in `app.configure()` ....

```
app.use(function (req, res) {
    res.send('<h2>Hello, your session id is ' + req.sessionID + '</h2>');
});
```

will result in the following (each line represents a new GET /session request to the app - node hasn't restarted either).

localhost:2000

```
Hello, your session id is sHkkESxJgzOyDhDwyTjwpNzq
Hello, your session id is sHkkESxJgzOyDhDwyTjwpNzq
Hello, your session id is sHkkESxJgzOyDhDwyTjwpNzq
```

api.mydomain.com

```
Hello, your session id is uuo4U5ierZAG8LSH1BdwTlVf
Hello, your session id is 8BxL97Bo35SDt4uliuPgnbia
Hello, your session id is 0xkqZZpzQNvTsQpbJtUlXgkR
```

**Setup info**

NodeJS v0.8.8

Apache v2.4.2

ExpressJS v3.0.0rc4

**UPDATE 2**

Well, I've so far resolved to simple use `mydomain.com/api`, as that seems to fix everything. So I suppose it's just something to do with how Apache handles domain communication with Express!

Comment: Notably, I tried the exact same thing with nginx using the config here - http://blog.argteam.com/coding/hardening-node-js-for-production-part-2-using-nginx-to-avoid-node-js-load/ but without ssl and produced the same issue as above. Is SSL a requirement for sessions?

Comment: I've had a similar issue while trying to replicate your problem - until I cleared my browser cookies. Can you verify that the problem persists after clearing your cookies? What browser/HTTP client are you using for the requests?

Comment: @zzen, using Chrome and Firefox. I've made sure to clear my cache whenever these things happen, but didn't seem to help. Noteably, I have got the reverse proxy to work when runnin on a directory, rather than a sub domain (eg domain.com/api instead of api.domain.com), which makes me think this is entirely an issue with domain handling in express..

Comment: can you also add info about version of node, express and apache? I've copied your code and apache config and got everything to work (after clearing my cookies).

Comment: @zzen that's strange - updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by [Apache ProxyPass and Sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676890/apache-proxypass-and-sessions) This apache config Maybe ...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName api.mydomain.com   
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:2000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:2000/
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Another great idea that should most likely work, but again, doesnt! I've also tried various other options `ProxyDomain api.mydomain.com`, `ProxyPreserveHost On`, `ProxyRequests On`, `ProxyVia On`, `ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain / /` but nothing seems to improve...

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to server.js

```
app.enable('trust proxy');
```

Quote from ExpressJS API Docs: http://expressjs.com/api.html#app-settings ...

> trust proxy - Enables reverse proxy support, disabled by default

Comment: Good idea, I did actually come across this. However, it doesn't seem to work. I've even added `proxy: true` to `app.use(express.session();
` as per the connect.js docs...

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this exact issue and tried everything else mentioned here without success. The final piece of the puzzle was adding the following to Apache's SSL Virtual Host config:

`RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"`

This particular gem I discovered in one of the last comments at https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/251

So overall the things I implemented to fix it were as follows:

1. Changes to Apache Config:

`RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /`

2. Changes to Node App.

`app.enable('trust proxy');`

Answer (score 1):

It should be trivial to look at the session cookie being forwarded and see why your browser doesn't re-send it when proxied -- the domain or path are likely wrong.

Re: your later comments -- Maybe you really did set "ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain / /" instead of using domains as the argument?

ProxyPreserveHost would probably also indirectly work for you, but fixing up the cookie is better.

Comment: I have tried setting ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain with actual URLs, but didn't seem to fix anything. As you say, ProxyPreserveHost is handy to have (actually fixes another issue I was having). I've compared the requests on both domains, and the response header from api.domain.com always contains a Set-Cookie header, while localhost:2000 only has it once, on the initial request...

Comment: Not urls either, domain names.

Comment: ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain args seem backwards to me.

What set-cookie is being issued by the backend? 
What set-cookie is the apache proxy converting it to?
Is the cookie being sent back? 

Hint, use a packet capture.

Answer (score 1):

Using this config maintains my session id on node 0.6.17, express 3.0.0rc4. Initially I had the following in the virtualhost, but even after changing to match your config, it still works.

```
ServerName api
ServerAlias api.internal.local
```

I get a Set-cookie connect.sid which is maintained.

Comment: apache version is httpd-2.2.3

Comment: I was hoping it'd be that easy - but from what I can tell, the only difference is the Apache version! I can't easily switch versions at the moment, but I'd be shocked if this changed anything...

Answer (score -1):

This happened to us to i don't think the reverse cookies stuff did anything to help our situation out.

I tried:
app.use("trust proxy");

to no avail.

however using

```
app.use("trust proxy");
app.set("trust proxy", 1);
```

Works.

Hope this helps anyone having proxy cookie issues.

Comment: This will probably break your app. App use requires a middleware function.