# How to pass session from apache2 to tomcat7 using proxy and virtual host

Tags: apache, tomcat, grails, proxy, virtualhost

I am using apache server to publish a grails app which is running in tomcat server.I am using sub domain to publish app.My virtual host configuration given below .

```
 <VirtualHost uxsurvey.abcd.com:80>
    ServerName uxsurvey.abcd.com
    ServerAlias *.uxsurvey.abcd.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    RewriteEngine on
    ProxyPass / http://abcd.com:8080/uxsurvey/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://abcd.com:8080/uxsurvey/
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyStatus On
        RewriteRule ^.*/uxsurvey/(.*)$ /$1 [P,L]

    <Location />
       Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

uxsurvey.abcd.com works fine but the problem is no session passed through proxy.I try to use sickysession but it not work.Please help me to solve the problem thanx in advance .

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/8676890/3340702

Comment: yes then i use those  ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /uxsurvey /
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain localhost uxsurvey.abc.com but it didnt work for me.

Answer (score 0):

At last i got the answer

```
 ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /uxsurvey/ http://abcd.com:8080/
```

works for me